# C# Lambda multiple criteria, child List

Tags: c#, list, lambda, filter

Would like to know if the following is possible, still getting my head around lambda expressions.

```
    GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
             && x.AddressList.Type_ID == 98.ToList();
```

The trouble with this code is that "Address" is a List. Essentially we would like to return List after 1) performing a search against UserName and 2) matching a property of a child list.

Semantically the code above does not work as 'Type_ID' is not available as a selection due to the fact that AddressList is a List, not a single entity.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: what does address contain a list of address.. what is its type.. does it has a Type_ID property.. please provide more code.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like?

```
GetAll(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(SEARCH) 
             && x.AddressList.Any(e => e.Type_ID == 98));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are extension methods that operate on lists, but it's still not clear what you want to do.  Do you want results where *any* item in AddressList has a Type_ID of 98?  If so, use the Any function.  If all addresses in the list must have that type ID than use All.  Here's some sample code:

```
class Address
{
   public int Type_ID { get; set; }
   public Address(int Type_ID)
   {
      this.Type_ID = Type_ID;
   }
}

class Entry
{
   public List<Address> AddressList { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public Entry(string name, List<Address> addresses)
   {
      AddressList = addresses;
      this.UserName = name;
   }
}

class EntryList
{
   private List<Entry> entries;

   public IEnumerable<Entry> GetAll(Func<Entry, bool> filter)
   {
      return entries.Where(filter).ToArray();
   }

   public EntryList(List<Entry> entries)
   {
      this.entries = entries;
   }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

   EntryList e1 = new EntryList(new List<Entry>()
      {new Entry("Fred with 1 98 address", new List<Address> { new Address(97), new Address(98) }),
         new Entry("Bob with no 98 address", new List<Address> { new Address(96), new Address(97) }),
         new Entry("Jerry with all 98 addresses", new List<Address> { new Address(98), new Address(98) })});

   var all98 = e1.GetAll(x => x.AddressList.All(y => y.Type_ID == 98));
   var any98 = e1.GetAll(x => x.AddressList.Any(y => y.Type_ID == 98));

   Console.WriteLine("Results for ALL:");
   foreach (var e in all98)
      Console.WriteLine(e.UserName);
   Console.WriteLine("Results for ANY:");
   foreach (var e in any98)
      Console.WriteLine(e.UserName);
}
```

The output is:

```
Results for ALL:
Jerry with all 98 addresses
Results for ANY:
Fred with 1 98 address
Jerry with all 98 addresses
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was down-voted... please post a comment when down-voting so we know what the problem is.  A good deal of effort went into this answer.